# Calculate distance to all polygons within a buffer/radius in R

Tags: r, distance, buffer

I have 2 data sets, one with polygons and one with points. My goal is to find the distance between each point and all polygons that are within a radius of 16 km using R. The data set is very large (2 million polygons and 29,000 points). I was thinking of creating a 16km buffer around each point and then calculating the distance to all polygons that are within the buffer. Another way would be to calculate the distance to all polygons up to a maximum distance of 16km. But I don't know how to implement this efficiently.
Does anyone have any ideas on how to approach this? I could also use QGIS, but prefer R.
My attempt so far:

1st. find all polygons within the 16km buffer:

`dist.max <- st_join(polygons, points, st_is_within_distance, dist = 16000, left = TRUE)`

Now i dont know how to continue and I guess the data would be too large.

Comment: You should probably choose R or QGIS, not both, or your question will get closed. If you want an R solution you also need to add a code attempt

Comment: I think there is a function in the spatialEco package related to fragments that might run this. I know that I did have to run this at one point and it was very long.